# How to override type defination coming from typescript library

Tags: android, typescript

I want to make properties of window.localStorage optional for my project. Below are the type definition coming form file path */Users/bhuwanjoshi/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next-5.4.20240122/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts*

```
interface Storage {
    /**
     * Returns the number of key/value pairs.
     *
     * [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Storage/length)
     */
    readonly length: number;
    /**
     * Removes all key/value pairs, if there are any.
     *
     * Dispatches a storage event on Window objects holding an equivalent Storage object.
     *
     * [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Storage/clear)
     */
    clear(): void;
    /**
     * Returns the current value associated with the given key, or null if the given key does not exist.
     *
     * [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem)
     */
    getItem(key: string): string | null;
    /**
     * Returns the name of the nth key, or null if n is greater than or equal to the number of key/value pairs.
     *
     * [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Storage/key)
     */
    key(index: number): string | null;
    /**
     * Removes the key/value pair with the given key, if a key/value pair with the given key exists.
     *
     * Dispatches a storage event on Window objects holding an equivalent Storage object.
     *
     * [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem)
     */
    removeItem(key: string): void;
    /**
     * Sets the value of the pair identified by key to value, creating a new key/value pair if none existed for key previously.
     *
     * Throws a "QuotaExceededError" DOMException exception if the new value couldn't be set. (Setting could fail if, e.g., the user has disabled storage for the site, or if the quota has been exceeded.)
     *
     * Dispatches a storage event on Window objects holding an equivalent Storage object.
     *
     * [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem)
     */
    setItem(key: string, value: string): void;
    [name: string]: any;
}
```

I need this change because I am developing a WebView for Android application and localStorage is optional in Android, and Android codebase changes are required to allow localStorage for WebViews.